# Linux Script run on Startup

Tags: android, linux, sh, startup

I'm looking to build CyanogenMod ROMs for android, I've followed a tutorial to setup the build environment.

This is the tutorial I followed: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_i9305#Prepare_the_device-specific_code

The only question I have is, instead of executing:
    cd ~/android/system
    source build/envsetup.sh

Every time I want to build the ROM, is there a way to run it on boot? I tried to create a script to do it for me and run it in the startup applications but I couldn't get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/android/system/
source build/envsetup.sh
```

It throws this error:

`kane@androidvm ~ $ sudo sh ~/android/system/build/envsetup.sh
/home/kane/android/system/build/envsetup.sh: 1: /home/kane/android/system/build/envsetup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: added the line 

source ~/src/my-android-git/build/envsetup.sh

to my .bashrc, still getting the error 

bash: my-android-git/build/envsetup.sh: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: my-android-git/build/envsetup.sh: line 42: `}'


oddly enough it works correctly if I type

bash build/envsetup.sh

Answer (score 0):

you can try add your code in ~/.bashrc. I think you always need launch a terminal to do your work. Then it will be executed when terminal open.